# Scala append value to multiple vector

Tags: scala, vector, multidimensional-array, append

I create a multiple vector like this:

```
val a = Vector.fill(3,0)(0)
```

It outputs:

```
Vector(Vector(), Vector(), Vector(), Vector(), Vector(), Vector())
```

I want to append an integer value into the first `Vector()`.

Result should look like this:

```
Vector(Vector(2), Vector(), Vector(), Vector(), Vector(), Vector())
```

I tried many things from the internet and this way but it doesn't work...
`a(0).appended(2)`

How can I do this?

Comment: Search for [mutable vs immutable collections](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bscala%5D+mutable+immutable)

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok what can i find there? There is only the difference between both or the explaining of use of one dimensional vectors... =(

Comment: You used immutable vectors and received expected result. You don't know why. That means that you have to learn more about differences between them and what is mutable and what is immutable in Scala.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Thanks, but is there no way to add a value to a multidimensional vector like my question above?
Because in an one dimensional vector i can add a value at the end of the vector with concatenation like " :+ "?

Comment: Dani, hello and welcome to SO! Please take the [tour], and read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Elements cannot be added to immutable types, such as `Vector`. You can read more about it in one of the articles specified at @Mateusz's comment. When you "add" a new element to a single dimension vector, you basically create a new vector.

If you want to add in the same way, you can create a new vector, for example like this:

```
val a = Vector.fill(3, 0)(0)
val b = (a.head :+ 2) +: a.tail
```

Then `b` will have what you desire. Still, after creating `b`, `a` is still the same as created:

```
Vector(Vector(), Vector(), Vector())
```

Code run can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/t1KJW4dDQPyBkz5vWaAlAA).

Comment: This seems a bit simpler and more flexible to me: `a.updated(0, a(0) :+ 2)`  the `.head`/`.tail` version is okay for updating the first item but falls down for updating any other position.

Answer (score 1):

In vanilla Scala you would have to do something like:

```
val newA =
  a.zipWithIndex.map {
    case (inner, 0) => inner :+ 2
    case (inner, _) => inner
  }
```

or as @SethTisue mentioned

```
val newA = a.update(0, a(0) :+ 2)
```

However, if you want to modify nested immutable data, something like [quicklens](https://github.com/softwaremill/quicklens) can make it easier:

```
import com.softwaremill.quicklens._
val newA = a.modify(_.at(0)).using(_ :+ 2)
```

Comment: involving `zipWithIndex` is unnecessarily roundabout. `a.updated(0, a(0) :+ 2)` will do the trick